# Difference between Spyder IPython and "normal" IPython sys.path

Tags: python, ipython, anaconda, pythonpath, sys.path

There are some modules I want to be able to import when I use IPython. I use IPython from the command line sometimes, and I also use IPython from Anaconda Spyder sometimes. I appended the PYTHONPATH environment variable in my .bashrc file to include the directory that contains the modules I want to import.

Now, when I start IPython at the command line, everything works fine. If I import sys, and type sys.path, the new directory I included is there.

However, when I do the same thing in Anaconda Spyder's Ipython, the sys.path is slightly different (has some extra directories) and does not contain the newly added directory with my modules.

Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

`.bashrc` is read by "interactive" shells (when you start your terminal containing bash). Running Anaconda Spyder's Ipython doesn't start any interactive shell.

You have to setup your `PYTHONPATH` on "login" by specifying it in your `.profile` (you'll have to logout/login to make chages effective).

Comment: so does that mean I should just copy and paste the line for PYTHONPATH from my .bashrc file to my .bash_profile file?

Comment: yep, something like `export PYTHONPATH=/some/path1:/somepath2/`